# How to know git push status without verbosity flag?

Tags: git, signals, push, bitbucket, verbosity

I am doing a push to a remote. Specifically, I am forcing the push to recreate the local repo on the remote, overwriting the latter's master branch.

However, I forgot to use the `-v` verbosity flag.

Since the repo I am pushing is quite big (5.2 G) it is taking a long time to push everything. However, even if I can see that it is working on my network (using `nethogs`), it is not giving me any output.

How can I force git to give me informations without restarting it with verbosity flag? Maybe sending some signals (such as USR1)?

Thanks